# Spring Boot Microservice Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices

I want to create a multi artifact spring boot microservice application in intellij idea. I can do that in STS which allows multiple artifacts to be created inside a workspace. I am not able to do the same in intellij idea as whenever I try to add a new artifact it gives me an option of new window or this window thereby technically rendering only one artifact visible. I need to create several spring boot microservice application that can run on different ports. I am using intellij idea 18.

Comment: Did you try to add a new application as new ``Module``?

Comment: An IntelliJ project can have multiple modules (if you import a gradle or maven multi-module project, that's what will happen automatically). If you want independant projects (i.e. separate gradle or maven projects), then IntelliJ will open each one in its own window (which is not a problem, given that the two are  independant). You can perfectly run one of the projects on one port, and the other on a different port, whatever your choice is. If you're not using a build tool (gradle or maven), then that's the first thing you should change.

Answer (score 3):

You can create it as `module` and that way you can have multiple modules in the same window.

Comment: Can you please share a link to how to do this, or instructions?

Comment: @Paul https://medium.com/backend-habit/intellij-idea-running-multiple-project-microservices-in-one-workspace-d61126fe0eef